# LTSpice print schematic to PDF with command line

Tags: ltspice, spice

I'm working with an LTSpice schematic that I have formatted to print nicely to a PDF.

Does anyone know of a way to do do this printing using the command line instead of needing to open the schematic with LTSpice and print it manually?

Answer (score 1):

This is very confusing to me: you say you prettyfied your schematic -- that could have been done only from the GUI -- yet you want to print it through the comand line?

Well, whatever the reason, you can't. The available command-line switches are in the help, under `LTspice > Modes of Operation > Command Line Switches`, and none deal with printing.

Comment: I use pandoc to product documents from combinations of different formats, like jupyter notebooks and word documents, into a single pdf. I current print my *.asc to a pdf and add it into my pandoc build script.


Without being able to print from the command line I have to manage two documents, the asc and the pdf, and make sure they the pdf is kept up to date. It's minor.

Comment: @progresseveryday That makes sense, but the result is the same, unfortunately.